Next.js 14 and Signals: Forwarding Server-Side Data to Client Components
How can I correctly configure an application in Next.js 14 so that in the layout.js file, located in the app directory, I can fetch application configuration data from the server side and store it in Singlas? I would like to use this data in other components. When I add this data, settings.value is empty, even though I can see on the server side that it is being added. Would it be better to fetch this data directly from the database on the server side? I do not want to use useContext due to the complex structure of this object. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?
my example code:
layout.tsx
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

import { fetchRestaurantSettings } from '@/services/fetchRestaurantSettings';
import { setSettings } from '@/signals/SettingsSignals';


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const settings = await fetchRestaurantSettings();


  setSettings(settings);

  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

here is my signals:
import { signal, computed } from '@preact/signals-react';
import { RestaurantSettings } from '@/types/RestaurantSettings';

export const settingsData = signal<RestaurantSettings | null>(null);

export function setSettings(data: RestaurantSettings) {
  console.log(data); // I can add data on server side
  return settingsData.value = data;
}

export const settings = computed(() => settingsData.value);

In this file, I would like to fetch the data that should be retrieved from the server side, since I also use configuration on the server side.
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import { settings, settingsData } from '@/signals/SettingsSignals';

const Test: React.FC = () => {
  console.log(settingsData.value); // it's null
  console.log(settings); // 'empty' proxy
  
  return <>test</>
};

export default Test;


You cannot use signals in server-side components（nextjs14）
